# Can I block on async code in MVC Core?

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-core-mvc

We all know [the famous blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) regarding blocking on async code by Stephen Cleary. In MVC 5 the following code deadlocks when requesting `Home/Index`:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public string Index()
    {
        var model = AsyncMethod();
        return model.Result;
    }

    private async Task<string> AsyncMethod()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(2000));
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

However, the exact same code doesn't deadlock in an MVC Core web application. The response returns *Hello*. Why? Does MVC Core allow multiple threads to run simultaneously within one request context? Is the ***Don't Block on Async Code*** phrase out of date when developing in MVC Core?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why?

ASP.NET Core is `async` from top to bottom, and it's designed for maximum speed.

As part of the redesign, the ASP.NET team was able to remove the entire `AspNetSynchronizationContext` completely. Some aspects of the ASP.NET request context were moved into the core .NET, and others were just dropped (e.g., `HttpContext.Current`).

> Does MVC Core allow multiple threads to run simultaneously within one request context?

No. The notion of a "request context" is no longer represented by a synchronization context, though.

> Is the Don't Block on Async Code phrase out of date when developing in MVC Core?

No. It won't deadlock on ASP.NET Core, but you still shouldn't do it.

"Can I block on async code in MVC Core?" Yes. "Should I block on async code in MVC Core?" No.

Comment: For those of you that would like a little more detailed explanation check this blog post by Stephen - https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html.

Answer (score 2):

This code

```
await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(2000));
```

might not be a great pattern, but it's not "blocking" in the same sense that Stephen's post refers to. To compare apples to apples, you'd have to do this:

```
private string BlockingAsyncMethod()
{
    Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(2000)).Wait();
    return "Hello";
}
```

Blocking on `Wait()` or `.Result` is the big no-no for MVC 5. To my knowledge, that is still correct advice for MVC Core.

Comment: Your example does not deadlock in MVC Core. I still  get "Hello"

Comment: @Kapol block != deadlock. Blocking refers to synchronously waiting for the result of an operation. Deadlocks sometimes occur when you block synchronously (with `Wait()` for example) on an async operation. It's important to note that even with a bad pattern (sync over async), deadlocks don't **always** occur.

Comment: Sorry, Nate, of course I meant deadlock. The thing is, as far as I understand, my example *always* resulted in a deadlock in MVC 5, whereas I cannot reproduce this behaviour at least once in MVC Core.

Comment: Also, originally my async method called an async MongoDB operation, which is probably very close to what Stephen described in his blog.